# Buffer Overflow errors when reading ConfigDelay and Manufacturer info from registry

Tags: c#, registry, drivers

This is a strange driver error which doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

I am running an application developed in C# .NET which our company develops.

I was monitoring the application using process monitor and noticed that it accesses the registry a lot. The output on Process Monitor looks like this,

```
Operation      Result           Path
RegQueryValue  Success          HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Enum\SWMUXBUS\SW_MODEM\7&6c4af30&0&5&0004\Driver
RegQueryValue  Success          HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E96D-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\0000\Properties
RegQueryValue  Success          HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E96D-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\0000\Default
RegQueryValue  Success          HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E96D-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\0000\InactivityScale
RegQueryValue  Name Not Found   HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E96D-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\0000\PowerDelay
RegQueryValue  Name Not Found   HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E96D-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\0000\ConfigDelay
RegQueryValue  Buffer Overflow  HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E96D-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\0000\Manufacturer
RegQueryValue  Buffer Overflow  HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E96D-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\0000\Model
RegQueryValue  Name Not Found   HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E96D-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\0000\Version
```

The app is reading this stuff every 5 seconds from the registry, so I would ask a few questions,

1. What is this stuff?
2. Why is the app reading this stuff?
3. Why is it saying 'Buffer Overflow'?
4. Could this cause performance problems for my app?

From what I can see the app does not explicitly read this stuff, so I think this relates to a driver on the machine (which is a netbook).

Comment: this may be more suitable for Stack Overflow.  if you want us to migrate it there, please flag for moderator attention.

Comment: Perhaps, but I thought that because it is likely to have something to do with a driver it is more of a hardware thing. If I run this software on a different machine I don't get the above registry stuff. Happy to move it though if that is agreed?

Comment: @peter: i think it's ok here; it's a bit low-level so you may have to wait a while before you get an answer.  SO would probably answer it faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like checking for finding a modem, seems to be some WLAN device.

"Buffer Overflow" is a normal return value of registry queries where the caller specifies a buffer that is to small. Often, you will query with a zero-sized buffer to determine the size required, and follow up with a second query and a large-enough buffer.